# Index on Couchbase not booting up

Tags: couchbase

I am facing an issue where my couch base is up but the indexes on the couchbase is not bootstrapping , here is the log:

```
Service 'indexer' exited with status 2. Restarting. Messages:
github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/common.CrashOnError(0x1532780, 0xc045488c80)
goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/common/util.go:406 +0x63
github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/indexer.(*indexer).handleStorageWarmupDone(0xc0420a0500, 0x15336c0, 0xc0456b4b60)
goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/indexer/indexer.go:4694 +0x9af
github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/indexer.(*indexer).handleWorkerMsgs(0xc0420a0500, 0x15336c0, 0xc0456b4b60)
goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/indexer/indexer.go:950 +0x1938
github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/indexer.(*indexer).run(0xc0420a0500)
goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/indexer/indexer.go:618 +0x182
github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/indexer.NewIndexer(0xc042095680, 0x39, 0xc0000001ed, 0x0, 0x0)
goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/indexer/indexer.go:337 +0x1f33
main.main()
goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/cmd/indexer/main.go:167 +0x12da
[goport(c:/Program Files/Couchbase/Server/bin/indexer)] 2019/06/18 11:16:56 child process exited with status 2
```

On My Couchbase query console i am getting the below error:

```
Indexer In Warmup State. Please retry the request later. from [127.0.0.1:9101] - cause: Indexer In Warmup State. Please retry the request later. from [127.0.0.1:9101]
```

I have tried to restart the server but issue remains same , also i check my cpu utilization it looks normal to me.

I am using

```
Community Edition 6.0.0 build 1693
```

Can anybody help me here.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the indexer logs: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/manage/manage-logging/manage-logging.html

Comment: The crash is happening as indexer is unable to bootstrap from metadata that is persisted. The cause of the error can be found in indexer.log in logs directory. Could you please check the error from the logs and share it here? You should look for error that reads "Indexer::Unable to Bootstrap Indexer from Persisted Metadata" followed by the error message

Answer (score 0):

faced the same problem today, so posting a solution. In this solution, your data will not be lost.

First Copy all your index creating commands from the Couchbase UI Indexes section by clicking an Index, so you can use these commands to re-create Indices

Some Commands are optional if you are using Couchbase inside Docker

docker exec -it your_db_container_name bash           [Optional]

cd ./opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/data/@2i

rm -r *

Now use below commands to restart docker container

docker stop your_db_container_name           [Optional]

docker start your_db_container_name           [Optional]

Or restart Couchbase if not using inside Docker

Now re-create all indices using create indices command.